# Magento 2, Google Tag Manager script in header creates display issue in cart page in IE browser

Tags: magento2, cart, browser, google-tag-manager

Throughout debugging I realized Google Tag Manager script in header leads to displaying extra text `---------Tracking code: Standard (Asynchronous) "Add To Car"-------` in cart page as follow:

[image]

Any clue how to remove this?

Answer (score 0):

There was custom code in GTM side which these line were commenting out in wrong way.

[image]